# handle a dynamically changing element and a scroll bar

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

[This is a screen shot of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOcJw.jpg)

Here is the html code

```html
<div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 350px;"><div class="scroller" style="height: 350px; overflow: hidden; width: auto;" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible1="0" data-handle-color="#D7DCE2">
                <div class="tsk-row clearfix">
                   
                    <div class="tsk-left">       
                                         
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Update/776eab95-d7ea-4b5d-9c58-1c736e071895">New task to check new build of 2016.4.18.1 </a>
                        
                    </div>
                   
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Index/45d76b1d-f665-4e29-b22f-5c9cd335a957">test</a>
                   
                    <div class="tsk-right">
                        <span class="label label-warning">Assigned</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="tsk-row clearfix">
                   
                    <div class="tsk-left">       
                                         
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Update/e78ed656-c8d1-4623-b2f7-a70876d80a9d"> test 2</a>
                        
                    </div>
                   
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Index/01ebc490-08d3-46f5-b9f7-139f3837e289"> test</a>
                   
                    <div class="tsk-right">
                        <span class="label label-warning">Assigned</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="tsk-row clearfix">
                   
                    <div class="tsk-left">       
                                         
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Update/9a992f63-f331-4e5b-a04b-b2e2bdbaa6c1"> test</a>
                        
                    </div>
                   
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Index/01ebc490-08d3-46f5-b9f7-139f3837e289"> test</a>
                   
                    <div class="tsk-right">
                        <span class="label label-warning">Assigned</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="tsk-row clearfix">
                   
                    <div class="tsk-left">       
                                         
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Update/36fe32fd-f06b-47da-99d6-b3fdc060528d"> New login page</a>
                        
                    </div>
                   
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Index/01ebc490-08d3-46f5-b9f7-139f3837e289"> test</a>
                   
                    <div class="tsk-right">
                        <span class="label label-warning">Assigned</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="tsk-row clearfix">
                   
                    <div class="tsk-left">       
                                         
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Update/0af36bce-755e-4744-b17b-85be5f263bf8"> new task </a>
                        
                    </div>
                   
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Index/a7a8967d-0945-4b69-95d9-59026a1181ef">Ongoing</a>
                   
                    <div class="tsk-right">
                        <span class="label label-warning">Assigned</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="tsk-row clearfix">
                   
                    <div class="tsk-left">       
                                         
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Update/8438470a-e19d-433b-8fa6-d6ff051db570">This is testing </a>
                        
                    </div>
                   
                        <a href="/WorkTask/Index/01ebc490-08d3-46f5-b9f7-139f3837e289"> test</a>
                   
                    <div class="tsk-right">
                        <span class="label label-warning">Assigned</span>
                    </div>

                </div>

                </div>
        </div><div class="slimScrollBar" style="width: 7px; position: absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 0.4; display: none; border-radius: 7px; z-index: 99; right: 0px; height: 300.245px; background: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div><div class="slimScrollRail" style="width: 7px; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; display: none; border-radius: 7px; opacity: 0.2; z-index: 90; right: 0px; background: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></div></div>
```

Here is my automation test case

public void openAllTask() throws InterruptedException{

```
List<WebElement> task=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".tsk-row.clearfix")); // get the list of total no of elements present in the task window

System.out.println("size of i loop "+task.size());

for(int i=1; i<=task.size(); i++){
        //find the element one by one using xpath
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div["+i+"]/div[1]/a")).getText());

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div["+i+"]/div[1]/a")).click();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.navigate().back();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // find the scroll bar and move the scroll bar by cirten pixles 
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]"));

    Actions act=new Actions(driver);

    act.dragAndDropBy(element, 0, (i*10)).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(3000);         

    }
```

I want to select each element from the window which is highlighted and also scroll the window down so that when dynamically elements are added then I can scroll down and read all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
//i am not sure about my css path is correct or not as no way to check it
// if it prints the text and size correctly, than it will fine but if not than please give the right css path.

 List<WebElement> elements =  driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".tsk-row.clearfix > div.tsk-left> a");

System.out.println("size is "+elements.size());

for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++){

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    WebElement elem = elements.get(i);


    //this line will scroll down to make element visible
    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + elem.getLocation().x + "," +(elem.getLocation().y- 100) + ");");

    //don't use this kind of wait, use explicit wait
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(elem.getText());
    elem.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.navigate().back();
    Thread.sleep(3000);


    }
```

Comment: js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + elem.getLocation().x + "," +(elem.getLocation().y- 100) + ");");

Comment: don't understand @ManojBhosale?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...
I need to do some changes in the above code but it worked, hartley thankful of you